# Getting the selected value from a drop down box placed in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pass the value selected from a drop down box placed inside a div to a php script which then inserts it into the database.

I was told that to access input element from a div use .

```
   ("#divname").text();
```

I fiddled around and found out that this is just the string of all options which is basically just all the text inside the div.

Could anyone help me to select just the value which is selected? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
 ("#divid").find('selectSeclector').val();
```

You need to select the select element from inside the div and use `.val()` to get the selected value. If you know the id of the select element then just do `$('#selectId').val();`. `("#divname").text();` will only give all the inner text values of all the elements inside the div including itself.

Comment: What says undefined? Post your html as well. By the way you need to replace the values in the placholders in my answer. Don't use as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have following dropdown box

```
<select id = "drop"><option value = "hello">Hello</option></select>
```

Below code will return you selected value

```
$("#drop").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the selected value of the dropdown using its element ID

```
var drpdwnid = document.getElementById("dropdownlistid");
var selectedvalue = drpdwnid.options[drpdwnid.selectedIndex].value;
```